# API for collect pearson correlation coefficients

Tags: android

I make an app which shows graphs. I need to calculate pearson correlation coefficients in it. My question is:
Is there an API or library can I use to calculatet it in Android or Java?

Thnank you all and Regardes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an java API provided by Apache,

**Package name** : org.apache.commons.math3.stat.correlation

**Class Name** :   Class PearsonsCorrelation

For Further info visit

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/correlation/PearsonsCorrelation.html